# URL being rewritten for href elements appending from ajax angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am appending a node to the page that I receive back from an AJAX request. the node is a big html/text file. I am using angular and nodefragment to append I was using innerHTML but that was having some issues.

Every thing appends correctly save one thing
the element 
`<a href="http://www.someother.site" target="_blank">` 
are being rewritten to 
`<a href="http://mycurrent.site/dir/for/angular/http://www.someother.site" target="_blank">`

Has anyone run into this before?

Thanks in advance